# Ignoring a column when joined column has more than one value

Tags: t-sql, join, count

I have a table, Orgs, that contains the following data:

```
ID   Name            AddressID
0    McDonalds          4
1    Starbucks          5
2    Burger King        7
```

I also have a table, Addresses, that contains the following data:

```
ID   OrgID   Address
3     0      123 Main St.
4     0      456 East Ave.
5     1      789 Young St.
6     2      5 Riverside Dr.
7     2      8 Lakeview Ave.
```

I need to create a select statement that selects the names of companies from Orgs table and their address. A company in the Orgs table can have 1 or more addresses. If the company only has one address, I don't want to return any address for that company. If the company has more than one address, I want to return the address where Orgs.AddressID = Addresses.ID

So my results should look like this:

```
ID   Name         Address
0    McDonalds    456 East Ave.
1    Starbucks
2    Burger King  8 Lakeview Ave.
```

I'm not sure how to do this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My title should really read "Ignoring a column when joined column has only one value". Not sure if it's possible to update my title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    O.ID, O.Name, A.Address
FROM 
    Orgs O
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT OrgID FROM Addresses GROUP BY OrgID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) X ON O.ID = X.OrgID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Addresses A ON X.OrgID = A.OrgID AND O.AddressID = A.ID
```

Comment: I wanted to fix your code. You left out a comma after O.Name but Stackoverflow doesn't allow changes of less than 6 characters. Can you change it? Thanks a million!

Comment: @AndroidDev, I've run into that exact problem when trying to fix a 1 character typo in otherwise good code!

Answer (score 1):

[SQL fiddle with a working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49e84/10)

```
SELECT O.ID, O.Name, IsNull(A.addr, '') as Address
FROM Org O
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT OrgID 
  FROM Address 
  GROUP BY OrgID 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) c 
  ON O.ID = c.OrgID
LEFT JOIN Address A 
  ON c.OrgID = A.OrgID 
  AND O.AddressID = A.ID
```

Comment: Exact same solution as DJ. Wish I could give you both a checkmark. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Difficult without the data itself, but something like this?

```
SELECT 
    orgs.OrgID
,   orgs.Name
,   CASE 
        WHEN OrgCount > 1 THEN ad.Address
        ELSE '' 
    END AS Address
FROM        
(
    SELECT 
        OrgID
    ,   Name
    ,   COUNT(*) AS OrgCount
    FROM 
    Orgs
) orgs
INNER JOIN 
Addresses ad
    ON 
    ad.AddressID = orgs.AddressID 
GROUP BY 
    orgs.OrgID
,   orgs.Name
,   CASE 
        WHEN OrgCount > 1 THEN ad.Address
        ELSE '' 
    END AS Address
```